# Structured streaming data stored in a dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

1. I've got a spark dataframe of following form:

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

schema_sdf_consistent = StructType([ 
    StructField("A", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("B", DoubleType(), True), 
    StructField("C", DoubleType(), True),
    ])

sdf_consistent_init = ([( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )])
sdf_consistent = spark.createDataFrame(data=sdf_consistent_init, schema=schema_sdf_consistent)

sdf_consistent = sdf_consistent.withColumn("ts", unix_timestamp(current_timestamp()))
    
sdf_cons = sdf_consistent.select("ts", "A", "B", "C")
sdf_cons.show()
```

2. I am receiving structured streaming data in following form:
   [image]
3. My aim: I would like to append the current streaming data to my dataframe in following form:
   [image]

Hence in such way, that the timestamp “ts” (e.g. “1653577048“) and the key (e.g. “A”) with its value (e.g. “33.2”) of the streaming data is appended to the corresponding columns of the dataframe. The missing values for the column “B” and “C” are filled with the values of the previous row of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is the "foreachbatch" function that can be applied to a data stream that converts the streaming datatype into a normal spark data frame so that functions like pivoting and joins can be applied.

```
The join can be made via a auxillary row added to both dataframes, like here:
    # Add row_index for join and perform join
    sdf1 = sdf1.withColumn('row_index', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
    sdf2= sdf2.withColumn('row_index', row_number().over(Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())))
    sdf_join = sdf1.join(sdf2, on=["row_index"]).drop("row_index")
```